# Context for "There are only two men in the world of golf can play like that."

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

Sentence (1) below is grammatically/semantically correct.
Sentences like (1) are traditionally explained by deletion of a nominative case relative pronoun. However, in my view, sentences like (1) are constructions of there is＋an independent sentence/finite clause.

(1) There are only two men in the world of golf can play like that.

What is more, in my view, sentences like (1) seem to be acceptable in Brithsh English, rather than in American English.

**Question：**

In British English, is the context (2) below right, wrong, or inappropriate?

(2) "Did you see him skip that ball off the surface of the water trap right into the hole?" － "There are only two men in the world of golf can play like that. Jesus and Jack."

Needless to say, in the context (2), sentence (1) is used.

Comment: Are you sure that sentence is considered grammatically correct? Deleting the "that" from the beginning of the relative clause looks very colloquial to me - like something that would only ever be *said* and not *written*.

Comment: Your sentence 1 is not correct grammatically.  It either needs to have "There are" removed from the sentence, or have "who" or "that" added before "can".  (Note: I speak from an American English perspective, but I doubt this is correct in British English either...perhaps someone more familiar with British can clarify.)

Comment: This is a follow-up to [an ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610727/context-for-there-was-nothing-could-be-done-for-him); I mentioned that non-native speakers should post here.

Comment: Please cite the source(s) or confirm that you created the examples yourself. Thanks.

Comment: @Biblasia See [my earlier answer here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/610730/470858)

Comment: @alphabet There are situations in English where the relative pronoun is optional: but the OP's sentence is not one of those.  A case where it would be optional would be, for example, "I said (that) he should go."  In such a sentence, whether the "that" is used or not, the sentence is grammatically correct.  But the OP's example does not follow this same construction, and is not grammatically correct.  Note the difference in parts of speech immediately preceding the relative pronoun. The expression "only two men in the world of golf" can all be a noun, the subject of "can", without "There are."

Comment: According to grammar books of mine, sentences (1)-(4) below are given.  (1) There's a man lives in China. (Quirk et al. 1985)  (2) There is a man at the door wants to see you. (Curme 1931)  (3) There is a man below wants to speak to you. (Jespersen 1949)  (4) There's someone at the door wants to talk to you. (Huddleston and Pullum 2002)

Comment: @Biblasia The OP is correct on this point. This sort of construction is (to my knowledge) quite common in informal speech, despite not really making any syntactic sense. It's very rare in written works.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Exactly. This occurs in speech but almost never in writing.

Comment: I don't think I'd advise a learner to imitate it, though. It's fairly uncommon and risks sounding too colloquial if overused.

Comment: @alphabet Perhaps I'm always around more educated folk, despite living in Asia where many English speakers are second-language learners: I can hardly remember a time where this colloquialism was used.  I'm not at all accustomed to it.  The (2) sentence mentioned by GWisdom sounds vaguely familiar--most of these examples just sound wrong.

Comment: @Biblasia I suspect learners are much *less* likely to use this construction, since they've been taught the rules for relative clauses more explicitly.